# Minitoc conflict creating aux error defcounter refsection

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, auxiliary-files, minitoc, texdef

While compiling my book, I encountered the following error:

```
(./Book.aux
./Book.aux:94: Undefined
 control sequence.
l.94 ...\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@write
```

[image: picture of the above error]

The thing is that a simple fix is to delete Book.aux and after that the code compiles fine. However, if I encounter a separate error in my compilation, after I fix that error, the same error pops up again.

Line 94 in aux is:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@write
```

I think that probably a part of my code is missing something, but I do not want to paste the all the code from Book.tex or Book.aux as it will be a whole chunk which most of it is irrelevant. I will be glad to edit this post if I were directed to what I need to provide from either Book.tex or Book.aux.

Thank you.

[Edited]
Here is my entire compilation code when successful, I am thinking if I need to watch out for the `minitoc(hints) warning: W0024` given at the back?

```
    This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Book.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/soul/soul.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/was/gensymb.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/wasysym.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minitoc/minitoc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minitoc/mtcmess.sty)
(./Book.mtc0)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minitoc/english.mld)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minitoc/english.mld))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks-add/pstricks-add.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
`PSTricks' v2.54a  <2014/05/19> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-plot/pst-plot.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/pst-xkey.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multido/multido.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/multido/multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-plot/pst-plot.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-tools/pst-tools.tex
`PST-tools' v0.05, 2014/05/12 (hv))  v1.62, 2014/05/12 (tvz,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-node/pst-node.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex
 v1.33, 2014/03/25))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-3d/pst-3d.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-3d/pst-3d.tex
`PST-3d' v1.11, 2010/02/14 (tvz)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-math/pst-math.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-math/pst-math.tex
`pst-math' v0.62 , (CJ,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks-add/pstricks-add.tex
`pstricks-add' v3.68, 2014/05/17 (dr,hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks-add/pstricks-add.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xlop/xlop.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xlop/xlop.tex
`xlop' v0.25  <2013/02/26> (jcc)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/genmisc/longdiv.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/avant.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-xetex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex2.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/alphabetic.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/alphabetic.cbx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)

Package biblatex Warning: 'babel' option is deprecated, use 'autolang' instead.


)) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/makeidx.sty)
Writing index file "Book
".idx
(./structure.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.de
f
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx
.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-0.mdf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Option `backref' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 296.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `pagebackref' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 296.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperindex' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 296.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `bookmarks' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 296.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)

Package biblatex Warning: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
(biblatex)                Loading 'csquotes' recommended.

(./Book.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex

Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \perthousand.


Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \micro.


Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0099
(minitoc(hints))                --- The titlesec package is loaded. 
(minitoc(hints))                It is incompatible 
(minitoc(hints))                with the minitoc package.


Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0040
(minitoc(hints))                --- The titletoc package is loaded. 
(minitoc(hints))                It is incompatible 
(minitoc(hints))                with the minitoc package.


Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0030
(minitoc(hints))                --- The \part command is altered 
(minitoc(hints))                after minitoc.


Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0023
(minitoc(hints))                --- It may be the consequence 
(minitoc(hints))                of loading the ``hyperref'' package.


Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0028
(minitoc(hints))                --- The \chapter command is altered 
(minitoc(hints))                after minitoc.


Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0023
(minitoc(hints))                --- It may be the consequence 
(minitoc(hints))                of loading the ``hyperref'' package.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
No file "Book".bbl.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./Book.out)
(./Book.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/uwasy.fd) [1]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 129--130


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 131--132


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 133--134

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 135--136

[2] (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pag.fd)
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" >
(./Book.toc [3])
[4] <use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" >
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 201--201
[][][][][] 

Underfull \vbox (badness 1715) has occurred while \output is active [5]
[6]
Chapter 1.
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_2.pdf" >
(./Book.mtc2)
Underfull \hbox (badness 1286) in paragraph at lines 245--245
\T1/cmr/m/n/12 in-te-gers (pos-i-tive, neg-a-tive and

Underfull \hbox (badness 2126) in paragraph at lines 245--245
[]|\T1/cmr/m/n/12 Order quan-ti-ties by mag-ni-tude

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 264--264
[]|\T1/cmr/m/n/12 Apply ap-pro-pri-ate checks of
[7]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [8]
Underfull \hbox (badness 3098) in paragraph at lines 281--281
[]|\T1/cmr/m/n/12 Extract data from ta-bles and

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [9]
[10] [11]
Underfull \vbox (badness 1817) has occurred while \output is active [12]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 488--498

[13]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 512--513


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 518--520


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 520--530


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 537--538


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 545--546


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 546--547

[14] [15] [16] [17]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 741--742


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 760--762


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 769--770


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 774--775


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 775--776


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 776--777

[18]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 798--800


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 805--806


Overfull \hbox (2.61047pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 808--828
[] [] 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 834--846


Overfull \hbox (31.98517pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 830--849
[][] [] 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 830--849

[19]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 862--863

[20]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 925--927


Overfull \hbox (2.61049pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 915--929
[]$ $[]$ 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 932--934


Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 942--958
[]$[]$ 

Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 959--966
[]$[]$ 

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [21]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 987--988


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 990--991


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 992--993


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1005--1006


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1006--1007


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1007--1008

[22]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1009--1011


Overfull \hbox (20.2353pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1012--1027
[][] [] 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1012--1027


Overfull \hbox (20.2353pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1028--1043
[][] [] 

Underfull \vbox (badness 3471) has occurred while \output is active [23]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1082--1083

[24]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1140--1142

[25]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1171--1173

[26]
Chapter 2.
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_2.pdf" > [27] [28]
Chapter 3.
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" > [29] [30]
Chapter 4.
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" > [31] [32]
Chapter 5.
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" > [33] [34]
Chapter 6.
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" > [35] [36]
Chapter 7.
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" > [37] [38]
Chapter 8.
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" > [39] [40]
Chapter 9.
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" > [41] [42]
<use  "Pictures/chapter_head_1.pdf" >

Package biblatex Warning: Type 'book' not found on input line 1314.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 1314.


Package biblatex Warning: Type 'article' not found on input line 1317.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 1317.

[43] [44]
No file "Book".ind.

Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0024
(minitoc(hints))                Some hints have been written 
(minitoc(hints))                in the "Book".log file.

[45] (./Book.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on Book.p
df (45 pages).
SyncTeX written on Book.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Book.log.
```

I have checked that when I disable the `minitoc` package and all the relevant minitoc lines, the aux error goes away. I can't quite tell what `minitoc` is conflicting with, but I guess that it may be conflicting with `toc` itself.

Comment: It's not really clear which of the mentioned control sequences is causing the error. Is it `\defcounter`, or `\@write`? The alignment of the error output is important here. Also `l.94` refers to line 94 in your `.aux` file. Sadly though, we need more information to solve this mystery.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, will add in line 94 for my aux file shortly. [Edited as above]

Comment: I think the problem is in the `.aux` file getting corrupt. Errors like "fragile commands in moving arguments“ can lead to corrupt `.aux` files. Also interrupting the compilation at errors may have the same problem. Don't worry: remove the `.aux` file and carry on.

Comment: I see, the thing is that everytime I meet an error in compilation, the next time I compile, I will encounter this aux error. After which, I will delete the aux file and carry on as per normal. However, the next time I meet an error in compilation, the cycle repeats again. Looking at the aux line 94, I am just wondering if my toc is getting conflicted with my minitoc?

Comment: How do you stop the compilation when you encounter an error?

Comment: I don't actually stop it. I just edit the error and compile it again. Should I abort it when I encounter an error?

Comment: You should finish the compilation in a proper way, how is dependent of the way you work, i.e. compiling in a terminal or using some fancy editor. Finishing the compilation means, the aux file gets properly written and closed.

Comment: Getting error messages is a normal and a good thing (think about a life without error messages, horrible), if you get one, don't panic.

Comment: I see, just checked when I disable the minitoc package and all the relevant minitoc lines, the aux error goes away. I can't quite tell what minitoc is conflicting with, but I guess that it may be conflicting with toc itself.

Comment: Minitoc states that it is incompatible with `titlesec` and `titletoc`. Try again without loading/using those packages.

Comment: An alternative to minitoc would be `etoc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Johannes_B, I realised that `minitoc` is clashing with `titlesec` and `titletoc`. Hence I am switching over to use `etoc` that does not create the error.